# Subversion on Ubuntu server - setup issues

Tags: apache-httpd, subversion

I have followed a guide for setting up a Subversion server and I cannot seem to access any repositories that I have created and imported from a Windows based SVN repository.

In the past, I installed a Windows app called Visual SVN that allows me to run a SVN server on a Windows machine. I had lots of repositories I made for it with many projects in it and now I want to migrate all these into my Ubuntu server.

I followed [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/C/subversion.html), and successfully installed SVN, added a user and configured the Apache 2 config file as such:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /windows/mediahdd1/Repositories/Spring
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName Spring projects
  AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/passwd
  <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
  Require valid-user
  </LimitExcept>
  </Location>
```

I also simply moved my repository (from my Windows machine) folder into that SVN path of `/windows/mediahdd1`.

I first created a dummy repository using the same guide I linked above and it creates exactly the same folders and files that I saw inside my own Windows repository, so I assumed that I could easily import my previous repository folder and it should work.

Anyways, the main issue I am having is that I can't access my SVN server from another machine using the HTTP or HTTPS protocol.

I am able to boot up a putty session and access it using `SVN co file:///windows/mediahdd1/Repositories/Spring` and it returns me what appears to be a list of files related to my project.

How can I access this remotely? Do i need to run SVN or is it running? The guide doesn't explain how to run the SVN server, all it states is how to install, create a repository, create users and different protocols you can use to access it but how do you access it remotely from say TortoiseSVN? The HTTP link doesn't work and that's what I normally use to access a SVN repo from TortoiseSVN or another SVN client.

Any advice? Do I need to change port? What is the default port for SVN?

Comment: Since you can access the repository locally, svn is working fine. Since you can't access it remotely, your Apache configuration is broken. Post the exact contents of your Apache configuration. In particular, in what file is that code snippet? Also, what error message do you get when you try to access the repository remotely? What messages appear in the Apache logs (`/var/log/apache/*.log` or something like that)?

Comment: @Gilles - or, firewall?

Answer (score 4):

Change `AuthName Spring projects` to `AuthName "Spring projects"`. The parameter needs to be in quotes if it has spaces.

UPDATE:

Since the HTTP access issue is more than just a syntax issue, if you're open to `svn://` access, I'd say give that go. This [link](http://www.gkspk.com/view/programming/setting-up-a-subversion-server/) shows how to set up `svnserve` on Ubuntu.

Since you've got it installed, you can glance over the bit at the begining, and carry on from the point where it is running `svnserve -d --foreground -r /var/repos`. Of course you'd replace `/var/repos` with `/windows/mediahdd1/Repositories`, and you'd access your repository from the client as `svn://<your_host>/Spring`.

Hopefully this one works out for you.

Comment: O ok. Done, how do i access the repositry using a  url? i tried http://xxx.xx.xx/svn and it diddnt work

Comment: Sorry, I presumed the error was with just the webdav syntax. In any case, getting `svnserve` running on its own is far easier than getting it to work with apache. So I updated the post showing how to set up svnserve.