# How to set-up a online SVN server on my laptop

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, subversion

I had created a local SVN  server on my laptop running Ubuntu 12.04 and its working perfectly fine. Now I want to make my laptop as server for some valid users who can access my SVN server though internet. I know how to add users and set  their password.

I used following guide to set-up a local SVN server [1]

This question can be considered as replica of [2]

But I didn't get exact answer. Through some links I came to know that I had to set my Apache server accordingly so that it is accessible through internet.

[1] http://oliverdavies.co.uk/blog/2011/10/install-and-configure-subversion-svn-server-ubuntu#comment-10209

[2] [Subversion on Ubuntu server - setup issues](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12828/subversion-on-ubuntu-server-setup-issues)

Comment: It would be much easier with [Git](http://git-scm.com/) imho ;)

Comment: @Wiktor: setting a SVN server is easy too but i will be thankful if you can tell me in what respect Git is more easy, setting up a Git server and make it accessible though internet or simply setting a Git server on a local computer.

Comment: Git is designed as distributed system so you actually don't need any central server and you can use SSH as data transmission layer (so you don't need apache). But you would probably need something like `gitolite` to manage more complex access list.

Comment: @shallendra Any distributed version control system would be a better choice, the more popular being [Bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/) (from the makers of Ubuntu), [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) and `git` (as mentioned by Wiktor). All three have pros and cons, but are IMHO all worth investigating as an upgrade for Subversion.

Comment: @Anthon: your advice is well taken.But in that case also i need to set-up my laptop settings accordingly so that when my laptop is attached to Internet, authorized users can access that repository.I am not from the field of web, so technical words used in reference to web may be wrong.

Comment: have you tried `trac` with `svn` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary to setup an Apache server to front your subversion server. That's only required if you want to make it accessible via HTTP and/or to allow it to be browseable through a web browser.

Where I work we just setup `svnserve` which gives you everything you need for interacting with subversion repositories. It's pretty trivial to set this up.

Given you're on Ubuntu I would take a look at this guide titled: [Subversion](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion), from the Ubuntu Community Wiki.

#### General steps

```
$ svnserve -d --foreground -r /home/svn
# -d -- daemon mode
# --foreground -- run in foreground (useful for debugging)
# -r -- root of directory to serve
```

For more usage details, refer to svnserve's help:

```
$ svnserve --help
```

The guide I mentioned above also includes the details if you'd like to setup Apache and have it provide your subversion repositories via WebDAV (http:// or https://).

**NOTE:** The approach I've mentioned above using `svnserve` is providing access to your repositories via (svn://) which is TCP port 3690. This approach works perfectly with any subversion client such as `svn` on Unix or TortoiseSVN on Windows.

Comment: I tried to configure my apache2 server according to the article given in your answer [1]. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion.Now i am able to get to my SVN repository through http:// locally.That was the stage which i reached earlier also.Now what i want is that my friend sitting on some other part of country can reach this repository through http:// or https:// or any other protocol.For that when i google, i found that i had do change my DNS setting or DNS server settin

Comment: I tried to configure my apache2 server according to the documentation given on [1]

Comment: I tried my level best to make it accessible to my fiend sitting in another part of country but it didn't happen.I followed http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1338564 and answer above.But nothing comes out.Can some one elaborate it further.

Comment: :Yes this is what i read on google that i had to redirect all the traffic coming to my router to my laptop(on which i had installed SVN server).So i think i need to so some additional steps for this.

Comment: You're going to have to be more explicit in what you've done thus far. Can you access this apache setup using your outsie IP address, for example?

Comment: No, i cant.I tried doing http://xyz.prr.ab.i/svn/test on my browser where xyz.prr.ab.i is my public IP.But it says that nothing found.I tried to search on this front and change DNS server from 127.0.0.1 to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 but even this didn't work.Even though SVN server is still working on my local host.

Comment: OK so your problem is that the connection from the router to your laptop isn't working. What type of router do you have? If it's something like a Netgear or Linksys, you have to do a port redirection of port 80 to your laptops IP address and it's port 80.

Comment: slm:i had tried to do so also, port binding with my public ip but then i faced on more problem regarding which i had asked a question at below link. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76433/binding-a-particular-ip-to-a-port-in-apache2