# Binding a particular IP to a port in apache2

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, subversion

In [How to set-up a online SVN server on my laptop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76183/how-to-set-up-a-online-svn-server-on-my-laptop) I asked to give access to my SVN server installed on my laptop to some of my friends siting in another part of country.I set-up a SVN server.I was able to access it locally but my friend wasn't.

So i searched on Google and get to conclusion that i have to bind port 80 to my public IP so that when ever any request come to my public IP , it is redirected to port 80 which in turn is used by process apache2.(This is what i understand after search, kindly correct me if i am wrong.)

But when I did port binding following [a link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-apache2-change-default-port-ipbinding/) I got following error when I restart my apache2 server.

```
service apache2 restart 
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                          [Mon May 20 13:44:25 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Mon May 20 13:44:25 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
(99)Cannot assign requested address: make_sock: could not bind to address xyz.pqr.ad.ef:8010
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

where xyz.pqr.ad.ef is my public IP and I added one more port 8010.

Need to resolve this error and get my SVN repo online for some specific users.

Comment: What does the `Listen` directive in your httpd.conf look like?

Comment: @JennyD: It is basically empty.it reside inside /etc/apache2/. I had seen some sample httpd.conf files, they basically are not empty, so is it is what i am lacking.

Comment: @JennyD: Well i read on the link that httpd.conf is basically blank by default in apache2 in ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Is the public IP address assigned to any of the interfaces on the system?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: No, i did sockstat -l and found that public IP is nopt assigned to any other interface

Comment: These types of issues are why I suggested in the question to use svnserve and not Apache. If you've never done this before setting up Apache can be difficult. I would forego setting up Apache and just port redirect to 3690 to the svnserve solution I suggested in your other question.

Comment: Then you can't bind to the public IP address.

Comment: did not using apache2 and only using SVN server will resolve every of mine issue including letting specific users access my repo via net?

Comment: No svnserve has password protection as well. Apache only gives you the ability to browse the repo, if you have an svn client this isn't necessary.

Comment: The link I provided in your original question as well this one provide the details for setting up a password w/ svnserve: http://queens.db.toronto.edu/~nilesh/linux/subversion-howto/.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue above is because you've specified this in your httpd.conf file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

But then you don't specify any VirtualHost sections like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   UseCanonicalName off

    ServerName localhost

    # subversion lines go in here
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: my httpd.conf file is empty.

Comment: Look at the files under `/etc/httpd`. What's the underlying Linux distro? There are differences b/w Debian based and Red Hat vs. others. Again another reason to avoid this if you don't know about it 8-).

Comment: i am using ubuntu-12.04 and there is no etc/httpd.I will try establishing only SVN following your link and then see whether i am able to do  svn co or not from a remote machine

Comment: Look under `/et/apache2`. Ubuntu uses a `apache2.conf` instead of httpd.conf for example, and there may be additional files under `/etc/apache2/conf.d`. Where were you making your subversion changes to get apache working if you weren't in these directories?